# Move negut v2 API to negut v3 api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to install some nuget packages but every time i get this Feedback

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error Failed to fetch results from V2 feed at 'https://www.nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Bcl.Build'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' with following message : Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).

can anyone help..
my project delivery window is closing very fast.

I have change nuget configuration from
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
to
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Am expecting the package microsoft.net.http to be added into the project